# Assigning a value of a promise to an object method

Tags: javascript, angularjs, object, methods, promise

Consider this object i'm creating.

```
$scope.formules = {};
$scope.formules = {

    label: 'some label',
    getYear: function() {

        // getData() is a promise
        $scope.getData().then(function(){

            // Some code to get the right data

            return someData;

        }.catch(function () {
         $scope.error = 'bad error';

    }

}();
}
```

At this point, getYear is undefined, obvious because i have to do a second return.

```
$scope.formules = {};
$scope.formules = {

    label: 'some label',
    getYear: function() {

        // getData() is a promise
        $scope.getData().then(function(){

            // Some code to get the right data

            return someData;

        }.catch(function () {
         $scope.error = 'bad error';

    }

    return $scope.getData();  //Putting the second return here

}();
```

or a shorter way could be this:

```
$scope.formules = {

    label: 'some label',
    getYear: function() {

        // getData() is a promise
        return $scope.getData().then(function(){ // Or putting the second return here.

            // Some code to get the right data

            return someData;

        }.catch(function () {
         $scope.error = 'bad error';

    }


}();
```

again this is not the right way because the second return just returns the promise so my method `getYear` contains a promise now, not the right way to do this.

**last try:**

```
$scope.formules = {

    label: 'some label',
    getYear: function() {

        // getData() is a promise
        return $scope.getData().then(function(){ // return the $scope.getData()

            // Some code to get the right data

            return someData;

        }.catch(function () {
         $scope.error = 'bad error';

    }


}().then(function(data){ return data; });
```

Now i run out of luck and ideas, `console.log($scope.formules)` shows me again that getYear is a promise, and won't give me the value.

Note: If i do `console.log(data)` instead of `return data;` i do get the value that i would like to bind to the method.

What am i doing wrong here, what is the right way to bind the value? Stack & Google did not gave me any answer...

**EDIT**

Here is the actual code that i use inside the method:

```
getYear: function ()  {

    $scope.measure = value.formules_total_year;

    $scope.getCube().then(function(test){

        var totalRatioData = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.tempData.length; i++){

        totalRatioData.push($scope.tempData[i][1].qNum);

    }

    return totalRatioData;

})


}(),
```

$scope.tempData is an array of 5 arrays. `[Array[2], Array[2], Array[2], Array[2], Array[2]]` and in those 5 arrays you have 2 objects

```
0: Object
    qElemNumber: 0
    qNum: 2009
    qState: "O"
    qText: "2009"
    __proto__: Object
1: Object
    qElemNumber: 0
    qNum: 225632.21000000002
    qState: "L"
    qText: "225632,21"
```

What i want as you see in this edit is a new array of all the qNum's of the last object of the 5 arrays and assign this array to getYear.

Comment: Where do you want to bind the values to? You can just do the assigning in the callback: `$scope.formules.years = someData;`

Comment: Stackoverflow give answer of every question. if you find proper string

Comment: What you're trying to do is not possible. You should show us what problem you're trying to solve with thaht `getYear` method.

Comment: Why are you trying to call an object? `$scope.formules = {
...
}();`

Comment: @hansmaad - See my edit above.

Comment: @nils i do not try to call an object. there was a brace missing, fixed it now. What i do now is call a method so it is invoked immediately

Comment: This does not help. Explain what you want to do with the result of `getYears` and how and where you want to call it.

Comment: Well basically what i want is an object where there are other objects inside i.e. `$scope.formules { label1: {label: "label1", getYear: [1, 3, 5, 2]}, label2: {label: "label2", getYear: [2.8, 2, -7, 9]}, ... }` so in my view i can do `ng-repeat="(forms in formules)"` and get this data publishes with `{{ forms.label }}` and `{{ forms.getYear }}`

Comment: `$scope.getCube().then(function(test){...}` but the data `test` is not used, Why?

Answer (score 0):

it's a bit hard to understand what you finally want to achieve and why you're "bundle" all the $scope assignments in your getYear() function. It looks to me, like you're trying to return a async value (totalRatioData) synchronous. the point here is, that this is not possible with es5. es7 will provide a new method called "await" which would enable that.

if you want to use the value of getYear on your view, just pass the value of the promise to your view model ($scope variable).

```js
// init ctrl
$scope.year = null;
_initYears();
    
function _initYears() {
  
  $scope
    .getData()
    .then(
      function() {
        
        var totalRatioData = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.tempData.length; i++){

          totalRatioData.push($scope.tempData[i][1].qNum);

        }
        
        // assign data to year
        $scope.year = totalRatioData;
        
      }  
    )
  ;
}
```

if you're using ui-router, I would suggest, to place your promise in the desired section of your state config to ensure it's resolved, before the state is activated.

hope that helps

Comment: Well for me it is not that simple to explain what is happening but basically i have a database where there are 54 formules inside. These formules are calculations that i can send to another program through web sockets. That program answers with an array of values. See the EDIT in my question. You could say i just want to group all the response in one object, whyle the program sends back multiple arrays.

Comment: do you use multiple service calls to get all the data required for your response object? if so, you can also group the promises of all calls and resolve them tougether with $q.all([promise1, promise2, promise3, etc.]).then(.... and then create your response object inside of your success callback

Answer (score 0):

You should not call for data inside your scope properties but in the controller.

```
function myController($scope, someService) {
    $scope.formules = { label : 'label' };
    someService.getData().then(function(data) {
      $scope.formules.year = getYear(data);
    });
}
```

Then bind to scope properties

```
<span ng-bind="formules.label"></span>
<span ng-bind="formules.year"></span>
```